# Errore GnuTLS -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received

Tags: server, vsftpd

VSFTPD raise this error after checking the password of users that don't have a shell login to the server.

I have it and I can login without any problem. This is the log I see in Filezilla:

```
Stato:          Connessione a 95.110.226.115:21... 
Stato:        Connessione stabilita, in attesa del messaggio di benvenuto...
Risposta:   220 Welcome to LSSF FTP service. Comando:   AUTH TLS
Risposta:   234 Proceed with negotiation. 
Stato:         Inizializzazione TLS in corso... 
Stato:          Verifica del certificato in corso... 
Stato:          Connessione TLS stabilita.
Comando:    USER grafico 
Risposta:   331 Please specify the password.
Comando:    PASS ******* 
Errore:         Errore GnuTLS -15: An unexpected TLS packet was received. 
Errore:         Impossibile collegarsi al server
```

To enable the users without shell to login I added:

```
echo "/bin/false" >> /etc/shells
```

How to fix? Where should I look at? I need to have some accounts that can ftp but not login to the box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue re-creating the user with a home directory.

My vsftpd configuration is set to open the home directory for each user but the user I created was without both the ability to login via ssh and the home directory.

With the home directory and /bin/false as a shell it works fine